# How to show data labels in charts created via Openpyxl

Tags: charts, label, openpyxl

I am creating charts using openpyxl with the following code.
By default it doesn't show data labels - so I have to right-click the chart and choose 'Add Data Labels" manually. How do I do that with Openpyxl command?
Thanks in advance !

```
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=6, max_row=10)
titles = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=10)
chart = BarChart3D()
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(titles)
ws.add_chart(chart, "C10")
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me on a line chart (As a combination chart):
openpyxls version: 2.3.2:

```
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabelList
chart2 = LineChart()
.... code to build chart like add_data()
and: # Style the lines
s1 = chart2.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "diamond"
... your data labels added here:
chart2.dataLabels = DataLabelList() 
chart2.dataLabels.showVal = True
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Worked for my BarChart as well: stacked BarCharts show datalabel within bar, unstacked BarCharts on top of the bar

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3d1928d04fb0> in <module>
     68 # 2.Create object of LineChart class
     69 chart = LineChart()
---> 70 s1 = chart.series[0]
     71 s1.marker.symbol = "diamond"
     72 # 3.set the title of the chart

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: hi man, this works like charm. Do you know how to style the data label such ass change the color of the font and the foreground color?

Answer (score 0):

Data labels are set per chart, per series or even per item within a series. At the moment you'll have to look at the source and work out how this works but `chart.dataLabels` or `chart.series[0].label` is the place to start.